¿Como puedo hacer para validar el funcionamiento del código de ML de XGboost?
Tengo un código de xgboost que está dando problemas con un dataframe que contiene 5 columnas de las cuales 3 de ellas se toman como variables de entrada y una como variable de salida, el dataframe tiene valores mixtos. el problema que arroja es el siguiente:
ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of y.  Expected: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36], got [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38]
he probado el código con ejemplos de seleccionar pétalos de flores con el dataset iris y funciona

XGBoost asume que la variable objetivo es categórica, con clases numeradas consecutivamente desde 0 hasta el valor máximo presente en el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento.
En tu caso, el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento esperado tiene clases desde 0 hasta 36, pero el dataframe real contiene valores que van desde 1 hasta 38.
Como consecuencia, XGBoost no puede identificar correctamente las clases y lanza el error.
El error que estás encontrando se debe a la presencia de valores en la variable objetivo que no están presentes en el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento esperado. Para solucionarlo, puedes modificar el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento o el código de XGBoost para que maneje correctamente los valores mixtos.
